# how to get all error information from the router and show in app

Tags: android, runtime-error, signals, router

I need to capture/get all **router error data** like how many times it was restarted, when it got hanged, heating issues etc and show the details in the Android app.

So how or from where can i get all these details of the router.

thanks

Comment: Sounds like a question about system administration / network monitoring, so it probably belongs on serverfault.com rather than here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing an app to retrieve these values then `SNMP` is the way to go. Your router vendor should publish the MIBs that your device supports and most your mainline vendors (Cisco, HP, Dell, Juniper) support things like temperature, interface errors, fan speed, alarms..etc

Even if your router doesn't support these it's still pretty likely it runs [RFC1213-MIB](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1213.txt) which still gives you basic information such as the router's name, description, location, contact, up time, interfaces, and IP addresses.

For Android, [SNMP for Android](http://www.artfulbits.com/products/android/snmp-for-android.aspx) comes to mind and might be a good library to get you started.